# eclipse doesnt show my galaxy nexus with android 4?

Tags: android, eclipse, device, nexus-one

i tried everything. Checked USB debugging and allowed unknown sources. (Android 4.0.1)

When i connect galaxy nexus with the PC without USB debugging, it works.
When i connect galaxy nexus with the PC with USB debugging, it doesn't work.

I can start my app on windows.

I have Windows 7.

Thnx

Comment: Have you checked device manager to make sure the driver is installed?

Comment: hi,  i have a new asus notebook. which usb driver? i searched it before, but i dont find anything. i tried >adb start-server, then adb devices, but nothing listed. I installed google USB driver package R4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in order to debug apps on the device, you need to install a USB driver first. although you may connect the device to PC as mass storage, you still need the driver for development. you can download it from the manufacturer Sumsung.

also,make sure you have installed the latest ADT plugin.

Comment: i have the new galaxy nexus with android 4.0. i searched the website samsung, but i cant find the driver?

Comment: it was the usb driver problem. Now i installed the USB driver from this here:

[samsung usb drivers for mobile phones][1]


  [1]: http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/down/cnts/toolSDK.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=9480&listReturnUrl=http://innovator.samsungmobile.com:80/down/cnts/toolSDK.list.do?platformId=1&indexType=1&indexDirection=1&sortType=0&cateId=1025&codeType=All&searchText=&curPage=2&listLines=&formData=number1&nacode=&nacode=

Comment: That's fine. I just searched the galaxy nexus on Samsung website, and it required me to input MOdel type, so I got stuck... My phone is not from Samsung.

Comment: I installed the samsung usb driver but still it is not showing the apps

Answer (score 3):

the samsung drivers have moved. this one fixed the issue for me

http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows

Comment: Thanks  a lot buddy. It turned out to be the issue after too many hours of stupid searching.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the USB Driver from Samsung: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I515MSAVZW#content2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install something that will avoid any future problem with every Samsung device, install Samsung Kies:

http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/mobilesoftwaremanual/mobilesoftwaremanual.do?page=MOBILE.SOFTWARE.MANUAL

Answer (score 0):

One confusion is that the Android docs mention the Galaxy Nexus One and Nexus S as needing the Google USB Driver. The Galaxy Nexus does not, it needs the Samsung one.

Answer (score 0):

Instal OEM USB Drivers:
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html
For Google devices install Google USB driver:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is where you get the drivers now: [samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SPH-L700ZKASPR)
Generally speaking you have to search in the manufacturer's website as stated [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)