# Galaxy Nexus does not appear in device chooser dialog

Tags: android

everyone, I would like to connect my galaxy nexus to the eclipse, which allows me to use the real device for debugging my program, however, my galaxy nexus does not appear even I have clicked on the usb debugging option in the developer mode. Can anyone give a hand to me, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Which operating system are you using?**

If on **Windows**:

- Have you installed the [ADB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Debug_Bridge) and [FastBoot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastboot)? Does your device show up if you do `adb devices`?
- If not, follow the instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) or [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html).
- Reconnection your device, open a console window and type: `adb devices`. If your device is listed in the output, Eclipse will also pick it up.
- For Samsung provided firmware and drivers, check [here](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads/SCH-I515MSAVZW).

If on **Linux**:

- Follow [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=883032) tutorial. You don't necessarily have to unlock the bootloader. As long as your device shows up in `adb devices` after adding the device identification lines in `udev`, followed by a `udev` restart with `sudo service udev restart`, all should be good.

[Here](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/how-to-install-adb-and-device-drivers-automatically-works-for-windows-linux-mac/) is another tutorial that claims to install [`ADB`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Debug_Bridge) automatically on both Windows, Linux and Mac. I haven't tried it myself. So it might be a good idea to peep inside the `Knives-&-Forks` scripts before executing them.

Comment: ok, thank you gsbabil, I have not installed this yet, so I try to fix it first.

Comment: I have installed the google USB driver, but the same thing sill happen, Windows still reply that it was unable to install my Galaxy. And I have checked for firmware by Samsung, it seems none of those firmware match my need.

Comment: @user1502740: What you need is to install the USB driver for ADB correctly first. Please follow the steps explained here http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html depending your Windows version.

Comment: I have followed it and successfully installed it, and open the usb debugging option, but the device still not appear, and using adb devices command shows that no device is attached

Comment: I would like to ask is it because Samsung devices need Samsung USB driver, because currently in the sdk/extras folder, it is google USB driver inside, so it will be fined if I install the Samsung USB driver here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371787/eclipse-doesnt-show-my-galaxy-nexus-with-android-4?rq=1 into the extras foler, then the problems will be solver?I have not installed it then, since I am not sure wheter it will affect the existing one

Comment: it is okay now, I think probably it is because Samsung devices need a independent USB driver, so it did not work before, thank you for the help you have given to me!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the USB driver is installed.  Instructions can be found [here.](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)

Comment: ya, I have read this and follow the guideline, however, at the last step, it replys me "Windows was unable to install your Galaxy"

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Galaxy Nexus driver from Samsung

[Galaxy Nexus USB Driver](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I515MSAVZW)